# SSIS-SMTP or Script task configuration file

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010, ssis, outlook

I want to send mail to people if warning messages occurs in my package ,someone help me how to use the smtp task component, when i was asking for smtp configuration details.

i was just provided with the below code here..

```
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "poorni@xyz.com"
objEmail.To = "poorni@xyz.com
objEmail.Subject = "load processing started" 
objEmail.Textbody = "load processing started."
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
        "tac-mailgate.prod.ds.xyz.com" 
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send
```

can you please help me in configuring with above code to send mail more briefly..

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you mean the "Send Mail Task"?
why are you using code? you just have to add the component to the control flow and configure it. Its pretty strait forward.

If you want to send error email messages, you can create e error event handler and add the task to it.